# Access S3 in cron job in docker on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-s3, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I have a cron job in a docker image that I deploy to elastic beanstalk. In that job I wish to include read and write operations on S3 and have included the AWS CLI tools for that purpose.

But AWS CLI isn't very useful without credentials. How can I securely include the AWS credentials in the Docker image, such that that AWS CLI will work? Or should I take some other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to avoid setting credentials on machines if they run within AWS.

Do the following:

- Go into the IAM console and create an IAM role, then edit the policy of that role to have appropriate S3 read/write permissions.
- Then go the Elastic Beanstalk console, find your environment and go to the the configuration/instances section.  Set the "instance profile" to use the role you created (a profile is associated with a role, you can see it in the IAM console when you're viewing the role).

This will mean that each beanstalk EC2 instance will have the permissions you set in the IAM role (the AWS CLI will automatically use the instance profile of the current machine if available).

More info:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html#use-roles
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html